# svn update skipped when the path is symlink

Tags: svn

I have checked out svn in the following folder.

/content/mobile

I have a symlink (product) in the /content folder linking to mobile.

product -> mobile

When I do
svn up /content/mobile
it works.

When I do
svn up /content/product
it Skipped '/content/product'.

Any idea how to make the svn update work for symlinked paths?

Comment: I've got the same issue, svn update simply says "Skipped symlink/dir" even though there are updates in the directory.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. I solved it by doing svn update `realpath dir`. It's annoying though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your situation - is the symlinked directory a working copy or repository of its own?

But the answer is *probably* 
 to use an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) instead of a symlink.

Comment: It is a working copy. Is it SVN limitation that it does not resolve the symlink? If I delete a file and run the svn command using symlink, it retrieves the file. If any new files are aded or modified then I get message skipped and does not do the update.

Comment: Pekka - it's really simple, the symlink points to a working directory. Running svn update on the symlink is what is unreliable. You would think that svn update would just follow the symlink and then operate as usual on the working directory.